# Getting the max value for each index, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing, data-analysis

I have a database of people's ratings for movies. I want to get the genres with the highest mean rating for each age. 7 year olds like animation 50 year olds like sci-fi the most etc.
[image: df.head() looks like this]

```
df = pd.merge(pd.merge(ratings, users), movies)
genre_group = df.groupby(["age", "genres"]).rating.mean()
```

```
1    Action                                           3.393617
     Action|Adventure                                 3.632035
     Action|Adventure|Animation                       4.636364
     Action|Adventure|Animation|Children's|Fantasy    2.875000
     Action|Adventure|Animation|Horror|Sci-Fi         3.600000
                                                        ...   
56   Sci-Fi|Thriller|War                              3.454545
     Sci-Fi|War                                       4.425287
     Thriller                                         3.704969
     War                                              4.000000
     Western                                          3.857456
```

I would also like to sort the ratings without moving the age indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by 'without moving the ages indexes'.
You need to reset_index and then sort:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.sort_values(by=['rating'])
```